# Not sure why the CSS selector is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't seem to find the problem in my code. It seems that the #fullpage section selector doesn't work for some reason.

I made sure all my sections have a set position, and it still doesn't work as expected.

My HTML and my CSS...

```css
    body {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     font-family:verdana;
    }
    
    #fullpage {
     height:100vh;
    }
    
    #fullpage section {
     height:100vh;
    }
    
    #fullpage section h1 {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     line-height:100vh;
    }
    
    #fullpage section:nth-child(1) {
     background-color:red;
    }
    
    #fullpage section:nth-child(2) {
     background-color:blue;
    }
    
    #fullpage section:nth-child(3) {
     background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="fullpagecss.css">
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.js">
      </script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js">
      </script>
      <script src="jquery.fullpage.js">
      </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div id="fullpage">
        <section><h1>Section 1</h1></section>
        <section><h1>Section 2</h1></section>
        <section><h1>Section 3</h1></section>
      </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        FastClick.attach(document.body);
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Really confused why it isn't working.

Comment: Seems to work ? https://jsfiddle.net/v9u8b42y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it is the selector.  Might be the markup.  The fiddle was not working for me.  Edited things a little:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.css" integrity="sha256-l0tJvh77claYa8GowKaFNxtuRWZICtwHTk7+0tgsiZY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-DYZMCC8HTC+QDr5QNaIcfR7VSPtcISykd+6eSmBW5qo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.6/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.extensions.min.js" integrity="sha256-SjXUPmxobD+vLCws0crIzpdBrHgDjs8jamhUMv0eRac=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fullpage">
<section class="section"><h1>Section 1</h1></section>
<section class="section"><h1>Section 2</h1></section>
<section class="section"><h1>Section 3</h1></section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

No change to the CSS:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  FastClick.attach(document.body);
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //options here
        autoScrolling:true,
        scrollHorizontally: true,
    navigation: true,
      navigationPosition: 'right',
    });
});
```

Not even sure that is the fullpage library you are using.  There are a ton of options when initializing.  With this one, the sections apparently need to have class="section" .

Comment: Also, you might need a key to use 3.x of fullpage ?

Comment: Yeah, copying the JS and  the whole <head> from your html fixed the issue. I don't understand why you decided to use that stylesheet, though. It still works if I use my own.